# in Java how to get a server datetime from a client

Tags: java, network-programming

I want to get the server date time and set this to the client using Java Socket programing.example when I pass the Server IP address it will return the server's date and time and set this to the client.
thanks in advance for your help

Comment: [*What have you tried?*](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 0):

1. new ServerSocket / accept
2. new Socket / connect / read
3. Server get time / write
4. client set local time

For each point you may find an answer in SO, and a [tutorial at Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/index.html).